# hp EliteBook 8570p wireless button don't turn on

Tags: wireless

i got a new hp EliteBook 8570p laptop. After installation  of ubuntu 14.04 amd64 alternate most things work except wireless.

the wireless touch button/switch above the keyboard is always colored orange which, reading the manual, means "off". does not change when i touch it.

how can i activate the wireless-switch?

thank you in advance,
Yusuf

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that it is enabled in BIOS, and if possible press it to activate the wireless before Ubuntu starts.

You can do this by holding the shift key while you boot, until you see the Ubuntu grub menu.  Then release the shift key, and press the wireless button one time.  When it changes from red to blue, proceed with the remainder of the boot process.

On my HP, the wireless button is very slow to act while Ubuntu is running.

There's an [old post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1011790) (2005) which indicates that a user solved a similar problem on an HP notebook be reseting all the BIOS values to default, and then resetting them to what specific individual settings they had before.

Comment: It is enabled in BIOS. I can use wireless in Win OS.

I've tried were talking about, but not successful

Comment: If you click on the wireless icon in the upper right corner of your screen, does it give you the options there of enabling wifi?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that WiFi is Enabbled in BIOS and also that LAN/WiFi switching is Disabled, also BIOS option.

On my Elitebooks (8440p, 8470p, 2740p) when WiFi is working - button blinks in orange/white. When it is disabled it is constantly orange. On 8470p I have had an issue with this Lan/WiFi switching - I was not able to switch Wifi on. So disabled option and Wifi started working fine.