# Ubuntu 14.04 wireless switch not turning on (HP 2000 Series)

Tags: wireless, wireless-access-point

I have an HP 2000 Series laptop, which wireless apparently worked yesterday, I let my best friend play on it, then noticed he switched to my desktop while I was gone. I later find out that my Internet isn't working on that laptop. So, I then notice that my wireless key was stuck in off mode, I first try going win to the BIOS and restoring to default settings, it didn't work. I also tried checking to see if I have any drivers to download, which apparently I had nothing. And, I cannot perform a fresh install as something happened after installing Ubuntu that locked me out of booting from CD/DVD. I also can't find a flash drive that has the ability to make a computer boot from it, I have also seen another post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489977/hp-elitebook-8570p-wireless-button-dont-turn-on) but it didn't work for me.

Comment: please use `lspci -v` the `-v` will show what driver is in use.

Comment: "disabled by hardware switch" means use your fn keys or hot key to turn it back on. It should be fn + F12 I think on your model. Make sure fn keys are enabled in bios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't use ndisgtk**

You say it was working fine the other day so lets get it working again. Start off with the following commands.

```
sudo iwconfig
```

What is the output? If it says something about a hardware switch, you need to use your fn key switch to turn wifi back on.

Also, is wlan0 listed? If so run the following command:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

If not, run these commands instead.

```
sudo modprobe rt2800pci
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo iwconfig
```

Now, it should be listed and wifi should work.

There's no need to install the driver when the driver is included as a kernel module `sudo modprobe rt2800pci` calls on the driver "rt2800pci" and puts it in use. wlan0 is your wireless device and `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` brings this device up. Please post any errors.

Comment: Apparantly, after trying this, every command got errors, It didn't detect a wlan0 for some reason (I tried once resetting the network socket because I thought something was wrong with the network, then I notice the wireless hardware switch is turned off, and pressing it did absolutely nothing.) Plus, it said "no wireless extensions" when entering "sudo iwconfig"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the appropriate wlan card driver is still installed. Put in "sudo lspci" and post the output

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/z5294u4.jpg

Comment: search for the driver for the network controller card you have and install that

Comment: Wait, how can I get the driver without a network? My other Ubuntu PC is destroyed due to failed hard drive and I only have a working Windows PC.

Comment: look up the driver, download a deb file, and install it that way

Comment: or use a windows driver and find a utility for ubuntu to install them and download the deb of that utility

Comment: The thing is the PC has no internet, I found a utility [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/ndisgtk/) but I can't find a way to download and install the .deb and it's dependancies.

Comment: here I'll download it for you and rapackage it in a deb file for you to install locally

Comment: I'll upload it to google drive. Dowload it on another computer (or your phone) pull the zip I give you onto your computer in some fashion, unzip it, cd in terminal to the folder it is unzipped to and run sudo dpkg -i *.deb to install them

Comment: here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxwYn8K9RD7ZZGltajhBYktJUFk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I had the identical problem -- same model number for the laptop, etc.  (As a minor difference, I had to leave the classroom and students messed with my laptop in order to postpone a midterm.  BTW, I now have some wonderful screen savers if anyone hates their friends.)

In addition to the suggestions above, specifically,

```
sudo modprobe rt2800pci
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo iwconfig
```

I found it necessary to boot to a slightly older version of the kernel (where the module was available), and add these

```
sudo rmmod -f hp-wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

Then, and this is actually harder than it sounds, I had to wait a moment or so for the orange light to go off. (I'm impatient. I'm certain I used some special magic words which may not have helped, but made me feel better.)

Finally, I used the usual menu method of turning the network off and then off again so I could enable wireless access normally.

Convoluted, but it worked. Everything returned to normal -- at least enough so that I could use networking to solve the dozen or so other brainteasers the students left behind.

(Professor: 1; students: 0. They didn't find the midterm because it was never on the laptop. I use that machine only for demos and lectures. Next time, I deliberately leave behind a longer, harder midterm. Snicker.)

Lingering Question: How did they cause the problem in the first place?